# Meteor HTTP GET crashing inside Mongo loop

Tags: http, crash, get, meteor

Getting quite a frustrating problem at the moment.

I am able to make a Meteor.http.get call, but when I put it in a loop bad things happen.

I am not 100% sure of what I'm doing, so any pointers would be great!

This code works - it's coffeescript

```
Meteor.http.get("http://some_site.com/feed.rss", (error, results)->
  console.log "results: " + results.statusCode 
  if results.statusCode is 200
    console.log results.content
)
```

This code crashes:

```
things.forEach( (thing) ->
  console.log thing.url  # it logs http://some_site.com/feed.rss
  Meteor.http.get(thing.url, (error, results) ->
    if results.statusCode is 200
      console.log results.content
  )
))
```

With this error:

```
node.js:201
    throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
          ^
TypeError: Cannot read property '_meteor_dynamics' of undefined
at Object.bindEnvironment (app/packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:48:44)
at Object.call (app/packages/http/httpcall_server.js:72:25)
at Object.get (app/packages/http/httpcall_common.js:40:29)
at app/craftcandy.coffee.js:112:28
at app/packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:307:7
at /usr/local/meteor/lib/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:173:11
at [object Object].nextObject (/usr/local/meteor/lib/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:485:5)
at Object.callback (/usr/local/meteor/lib/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:478:12)
at Array.0 (/usr/local/meteor/lib/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:197:36)
at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:41)
```

Exited with code: 1
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.

Comment: This was a bug in Meteor's `Cursor.prototype.forEach`, now fixed in 0.3.4.  Your post caught it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be because meteor uses node.js under the hood, and node.js is asynchronous and non-blocking.

So, instead of checking for the results.statusCode, maybe put in callbacks (pardon my coffeescript):

```
things.forEach( (thing) ->
   console.log thing.url  # it logs http://some_site.com/feed.rss
   Meteor.http.get(thing.url, (error, results) ->
      results.on('data', (d) ->
        //Do something here with the data stream
      )

      results.on('end', (rslts) ->
         //Do something here with the results stream, like log to console:
         console.log rslts.content
      )
   )
)
```

Sorry ahead of time if the script syntax is wrong. As I said, I don't speak coffeescript (yet).

But you get the gist.   I cannibalized this from a [node.js question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893167/node-js-http-get-function-is-not-responding).  Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suspect that either theres something wrong with your code I don't see or one of your URLs is mal-formatted. You can try testing it like this:

```
Things.find().forEach(function(thing){
  var url = thing.url;
  console.log("geting " + url);
  (function (_url){
    try{
      Meteor.http.get(_url, function(error, results){
        if(results.statusCode === 200){
          console.log("request success: " + _url);
        } else {
          console.log("request error: " + _url);
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      // if it gets here you probly have a malformed url
      console.log("meteor error!: "+_url);
    }
  })(url);
});
```

Here's my *untested* attempt at translating that to coffeestript:

```
Things.find().forEach (thing) ->
  url = thing.url
  console.log "geting: " + url
  go = (_url) ->
    try
      Meteor.http.get _url, (error, results) ->
        if results.statusCode is 200
          console.log "request success: " + _url
        else 
          console.log "request error: " + _url

    catch e
      # if it gets here you probly have a malformed url
      console.log "meteor error!: "+ _url

  go url
```